# Want to read String with Name, Values, Null, Time stamp in list using python

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have following string

```
"9718436'~''~'355373'~'1913853'~'21'~''~'BLERS'~'1'~'1'~'2003-12-09 16:52:48'~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~'New_Rating'~''~''~'2008-12-31 00:00:00'~''~''~''#@#@#"
```

and want to read this as one tuple in list as follows

```
[('9718436','NULL','355373','1913853','21','NULL','BLERS','1','1','2003-12-09 16:52:48','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','New Rating','NULL','NULL','2008-12-31 00:00:00','NULL','NULL','NULL')]
```

I am currently using filter function"filter(None,re.split(r'\W', abovestring))" which is throwing garbage data in list.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is very nearly:

```
s.split("'~'")  # where s is your original string.
```

You could make it closer by doing:

```
[v if v else "NULL" for v in s.split("'~'")]
```

but ultimately you've gotta figure out how to deal with the trailing `'#@#@#` in some sort of logical way. That doesn't look like a null to me.

Comment: Thank you Adam for response.
This helped me. I made all the separator as '~' and later split with same.